# How to place a JCheckBox next to every data displayed from database in Jtable using java in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I have to 2 tables. `JTable1` and `Jtable2`. Jtable1 has data displayed from the database. Jtable2 should be having `checkbox` for every row in Jtable1.  I want number of rows in Jtable2 equal Jtable1. These 2 tables are beside eachother.

Here is an example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmVEG.jpg]

In this example there is a checkbox beside every data item. I want a checkbox generated in `JTable2` for every data item in `Jtable1`.

Here is a picture to get a better idea:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNvNa.png]

Here is code:

```
   public void fetch()
     {

    try
    {

    String sqlp = "select * from american";
 pst =   (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sqlp);   
  rs =    (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sqlp);

   jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


  row =jTable1.getRowCount();

   while(i!=row)
     {
    jTable2.add(check);
    }  
    }
   catch(Exception ex )
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
  }

    }
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach after reviewing these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20getcolumnclass%20jcheckbox%20).

Comment: i want checkbox itself to be displayed. Not any selected values or anything.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

Comment: this example shows selection of checkboxes. In my case, checkbox itself is not showing for every value in the 1st table. I want just the checkbox in each row of column 'choice' for each row in `JTable1`

Comment: Please cite an example that conforms to your requirements.

Comment: I edited the post. Posted an example

Comment: I need help in this, none of the questions similar to this have answered my question. I really need help. Please do not mark this duplicate

Comment: Without your [mcve], I don't know where you're stuck, so I really don't know where to start. If your question is is not a duplicate, then it's certainly too broad.

Comment: You might start with this complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513)

Answer (score 1):

```
jTable2.add(check);
```

You can't just add a JCheckBox to every row in the table. A table does not contain Swing components. It renders data contained in the `TableModel` of the table.

You need to add data (representing a check box) to the `TableModel` used by the table.

The `DbUtils` class returns a `TableModel` complete with data. So you have a couple of options:

1. Use the `DefaultTableModel` returned by the `DbUtils` class and add a new column of data to the model. Read the `DefaultTableModel` API. You can use the `addColumn(...)` method to add a new column of data to the model.

The column is added to the end of the model so you will then need to change the view of the table to display the column at the beginning of the table. You can use the `moveColumn(...)` method of the `JTable` to do this.

Finally when you create the JTable you will need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method to return `Boolean.class` so the proper renderer/editor can be used.

2. Another option is to create a custom TableModel that wraps your current model with a checkbox. Check out: [How to add checkbox in Jtable populated using rs2xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445418/how-to-add-checkbox-in-jtable-populated-using-rs2xml/32446003#32446003) for an example of this approach
3. Finally, just don't use DbUtils, then you can be fully in control of the data in your TableModel. Check out: [Java Resultset to JTable with Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780154/java-resultset-to-jtable-with-checkbox/32785955#32785955) for an example of this approach.