# how to display image from database in MySQL into jTable in java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

In a project I am working on I have showStudents.java that enables me to view all the students in the database in a jTable swing component. The jTable is correctly displayed except that the image is showing as

```
    5   Debebe  Gemesa  2020-02-07  Adama       AB  0956852145  1   [B@522d8811
    6   Samuel  Gemeda  2020-02-05  Bahir Dar   A+  0986451278  1   [B@3330a9d5
```

The last column is supposed to be image column. In the database I have the following values for students table

```
6 Samuel Gemeda 2020-02-05 Bahir Dar A+ 0986451278 1 [BLOB - 32 B]
```

I have this method in my showStudents.java that enables me to view all the columns from my database.

```
public void showRecord(){
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to read the data in the blob into a Java image.

Comment: @NomadMaker Can you help with how I can do that some code please?

Comment: Not in a comment. Google "java display jpg image" (or whatever type of image you have). There are lots of examples.

Comment: `try { stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            Blob aBlob = rs.getBlob("photo");
            InputStream is = aBlob.getBinaryStream(0, aBlob.length());
            BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(is);
            Image image = imag;
            ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon(image);
            jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } ` but it is displaying `java.sql.SQLException: Before start of the result set`

Comment: You are not connecting to a database in PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin is a query tool for MySQL databases written in PHP.

Comment: The _Before start of the result set_ error is a result of calling a `getXXX` method before calling `next()` on a result set. A result set is initially positioned **before** the result set. Also, please [edit] your question with details, don't add them in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DbUtils, then you will need to use a custom renderer to display the data. That is you will need to convert the `Blob` to an `ImageIcon` and add the `Icon` to a `JLabel`. This conversion would be done every time the cell of the table is rendered which is not very efficient.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Or the other approach is to NOT use DbUtils. Instead you read the data from the database into the `DefaultTableModel` yourself. The advantage of this approach is that you create the `ImageIcon` once, when the data is loaded, then you use the default Icon renderer of the `JTable` to display the Icon.

See: [How to get a DefaultTableModel object's data into a subclass of DefaultTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627828/how-to-get-a-defaulttablemodel-objects-data-into-a-subclass-of-defaulttablemode/55635012#55635012) for an example of reading the data directly into the table model.

You would need to modify the code to convert the Blob to an `ImageIcon` for your last column.