# Why isn't JTable ModelListener working and how do you save JTabel cell edits to DB?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

My goal is to be able to edit a JTable cell that, once edited and saved, saves the value into the database and loads the value onto the JTable. Currently, once I try to edit a JTable cell and press enter, the data does not get saved. I have realized that the TableModelListener is not being called; the system.out code in the actualizeTable model is not working.

The following code is for the Frame; I have taken out some codes (namely the JButton ActionListeners) as they are deemed unnecessary for this topic.

```
public class InventoryFrame extends JFrame{
    DatabaseManager dbman;
    private JPanel p  = new JPanel();
    private final JButton getAll = new JButton("Get All");
    private final JButton add = new JButton("Add");
    private final JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");
    private final JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
    
    private ResultSet rs;
    
    private JTable jt;
    public InventoryFrame() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        setTitle("Inventory");
        setSize(800,600);
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        isResizable();
        
        getContentPane().add(p);
        p.add(getAll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        dbman = new DatabaseManager();
        if(null == rs) {
            rs = dbman.getAllQuery();
        }
        InventoryTableModel itm = new InventoryTableModel(rs);
        getAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                jt = new JTable(itm);
                jt.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                jt.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
                
                /*if (jt.getCellEditor() != null) {
                    jt.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                }*/
                
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
                p.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                pack();
                setSize(800,600);
                doLayout();
                
            }
        });
        itm.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actualizeTable(e);
            }
        });
    public void actualizeTable(TableModelEvent e) {
        System.out.println("entering editing..."+e.getType()+", "+TableModelEvent.UPDATE);
        if ((int) e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            System.out.println("editing...");
            InventoryTableModel model = (InventoryTableModel) ((TableModel) e.getSource());
            int row = e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();
            String input = String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(jt.getSelectedRow(), jt.getSelectedColumn()));
            dbman.update(column, input);
            model.setValueAt(input, row, column);
            
            pack();
            setSize(800,600);
            doLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my InventoryTableModel class:

```
public class InventoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ResultSet rset;
    private int rowCount = 0;
    private int columnCnt=0;
    private String columnName = "";
    public InventoryTableModel(ResultSet rs){
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        rset = rs;
        
        try {
            if(rset.last()) {
                rowCount = rset.getRow();
            }
            columnCnt = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnCnt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if(!rset.absolute(row+1)) {
                return null;
            }
            Object value = rset.getObject(col +1);
            //System.out.println("value is: "+value);
            return value;
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        try {
            String colName = rset.getMetaData().getColumnName(col+1);
            if (colName.equals("ProductID")) {
                return "Product ID";
            } else if (colName.equals("ProductName")){
                return "Product Name";
            } else if (colName.equals("DateAdded")) {
                return "Date Added";
            }
            return colName;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the update() method that is called and parts of the DatabaseManager class:

```
public DatabaseManager() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory", username, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Successfully Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        
    }

    }
    public ResultSet getAllQuery() {
        try {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from inventory");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
    public void update(int col, String input) {
        String colName = "";
        if (col == 1) {
            colName = "ProductID";
        } else if (col == 2) {
            colName = "ProductName";
        } else if (col == 3) {
            colName = "Price";
        } else if (col == 4) {
            colName = "Quantity";
        } else if (col == 5) {
            colName = "Description";
        } else if (col == 6) {
            colName = "Category";
        } else if (col == 7) {
            colName = "DateAdded";
        }
        try {
            String query = "UPDATE INVENTORY "
                    + "SET "+colName+ "= ?"
                    + " WHERE PRODUCTID = ?";
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            
            pstatement.setString(1, input);
            pstatement.setInt(2, col);
            
            pstatement.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to be able to edit a JTable cell that, once edited and saved, saves the value into the database and loads the value onto the JTable.

Your understanding of the `JTable` and/or `TableModelListener` is incorrect.

When you edit a cell in the `JTable`, the data will be stored in the `TableModel` via the `setValueAt(...)` method. The `setValueAt()` method will then invoke the `TableModelListener` to indicate that a change to the `TableModel` has occured.

You don't get the `TableModelEvent` because your `TableModel` doesn't implement the `setValueAt(...)` method.

I would suggest there is no need for you to create a custom `TableModel`. Instead, copy the data from your `ResultSet` to the `DefaultTableModel` and then use the `DefaultTableModel` in your `JTable`.

The `DefaultTableModel` does implement `setValueAt(...)`. So when you edit the `JTable`, the data will be saved to the `TableModel` and the `TableModelEvent` will be generated. In the `TableModelListener` you can then update your database.

Check out: [How to get a DefaultTableModel object's data into a subclass of DefaultTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627828/how-to-get-a-defaulttablemodel-objects-data-into-a-subclass-of-defaulttablemode/55635012#55635012) for an example that shows how to generically load data from a `ResultSet` to the `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: So I have added and coded the setValueAt method for the TableModel. However, my main problem is that the TabelModelListener is never getting called, even when I double-click a cell, change the value, and press enter. The data value goes back to its original value and nothing gets updated. How do you fix this?

Comment: @GrantHu, *the TabelModelListener is never getting called* - You haven't implemented the setValueAt(). method correctly. it is the responsibility of the `TableModel` to generate the `TableModelEvent`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for an example on how to do this. I still maintain there is no reason for the custom TableModel. *The data value goes back to its original value* - the setValueAt() method is not implemented correctly or you have another logic error.

Comment: I've already explained to you how most people work with a JTable and a database. Its simpler and less error prone. Good luck.