# I want to display my excel sheet in a JTable in java

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

I have 3 classes called boundary, controller and entity. I am not allowed to access the boundary class straight from the entity class. I have to use the controller class to communicate with the boundary and entity class. The entity class consist of all my methods and getters/setters. The controller will check to see if the table is available. if return true, it will send the class over to the GUI.

What I am trying to do is:
I am trying to display the excel sheet in my entity class and then pass it to my controller then from there I parse the data to the GUI which consist the main method to display the table.

I have tried to look up the internet but the examples are mostly all from the main method itself.

It will be of great help if you can refer me to a link that I can refer to or advice me on what I can do! Thank you! :)

This is what I had done so far if someone says that I hadn't tried before asking :)

**The method from my entity class trying to call for the excel sheet.**

```
public boolean getAllBugs1(ListBugReportEntity ListBugReportEntity) throws IOException 
{
    
    Vector headers = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    
    File file = new File("src/BugReportDB.xls");
    try {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    headers.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
    Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(i, 0);
    headers.add(cell1.getContents());
    }
    data.clear();
    for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
    Vector d = new Vector();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
    d.add(cell.getContents());
    }
    d.add("\n");
    data.add(d);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

**The controller to check if there is such class or excel sheet**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ListBugController {

ListBugReportEntity ListBugReportEntity = new ListBugReportEntity();

public boolean getAll(ListBugReportEntity ListBugReportEntity) throws IOException
{
    if(ListBugReportEntity.getAllBugs1(ListBugReportEntity))
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

}
```

**The boundary class that I am trying to call the method in my entity class to display the excel sheet into a JTable.**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ListBugReportUI extends JFrame{

private JLabel sBug;
private JTextField sBugF;
private JLabel sAssignee;
private JTextField sAssigneeF;
private JButton searchB;
private JTextField searchF;
private JLabel search;
private JPanel panel1;
private boolean help;
private boolean what;
private JPanel panel2;
private Container c;

ListBugReportEntity ListBugReportEntity = new ListBugReportEntity();

public ListBugReportUI() throws IOException
{
    setTitle("View All Bugs");
    
    c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null); 
    
    sBug = new JLabel("List of Bugs"); 
    sBug.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
    sBug.setSize(300, 30); 
    sBug.setLocation(225, 30); 
    c.add(sBug);
    
    search = new JLabel("Search By"); 
    search.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20)); 
    search.setSize(100, 20); 
    search.setLocation(100, 100); 
    c.add(search);
    
    searchF = new JTextField(); 
    searchF.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15)); 
    searchF.setSize(190, 20); 
    searchF.setLocation(300, 100); 
    c.add(searchF);
    
    //table
    
    ListBugController ui = new ListBugController();
    ListBugReportEntity ui2 = new ListBugReportEntity();
    
   
    
    help = ui.getAll(ListBugReportEntity);
    
    Vector headers = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();

    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,headers);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
    table.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    
    c.add(scroll);
    
    //end table
    
    
    
    
    
}



public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ListBugReportUI ui = new ListBugReportUI();
        
        ui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ui.setSize(700,600);
        ui.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55635012/131872. It demonstrates how to create the header and data Vectors using the data from a ResultSet. So the basic logic would be the same except your code would get the data from the Workbook class. So modify the code to use the Workbook instead of the ResultSet. Or you can also search the forum/web for example that use the Workbood and DefaultTableModel classes.