# The cursor in the GUI is letting the user erase the displayed text on the interface

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am new to GUI and I am trying to print a table in a database on the GUI window, I used the JTextArea in order to allow new lines on the window.

However, when the GUI shows up, I can easily erase them with my cursor! How can I prevent that?

```
String toPrintOnGUI = "";
while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        toPrintOnGUI += (resultSet.getString(i) + " \t");
    }
    toPrintOnGUI = toPrintOnGUI.substring(0, toPrintOnGUI.length() - 1);
    toPrintOnGUI += "\n";
}
JTextArea label = new JTextArea(toPrintOnGUI);
label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel.add(label);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to print a table in a database on the GUI window

Typically you would use a JTable for something like this so the data is nicely formatted. See: [How to get a DefaultTableModel object's data into a subclass of DefaultTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627828/how-to-get-a-defaulttablemodel-objects-data-into-a-subclass-of-defaulttablemode/55635012#55635012) for a basic example.

> I can easily erase them with my cursor! How can I prevent that?

But if you really want to use a JTextArea then you can make the text area non-editable:

```
label.setEditable( false );
```

Comment: Thankkkkkkkk youuuu so muchhhhhh!