# How to populate a Jtable in another Jframe created using netbeans GUI editor with specifc data from MYSQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I created a query to get the required data but have failed to get the `JTable` to populate. The table just appears empty.

Essentially, I want to get an ID from one `JFrame` click a button, and open another frame that contains a table connected to the database but now only have it display data related to that ID instead of all the data in that database.

Is there another way I could execute what I want to do?

**Update:** Managed to figure it out, turns out it was the if statement messing with my `rs.next()` value causing the while statement not to execute and the lack of columns added to the model for the values to be populated under.

```
FamilyProfile one = new FamilyProfile();
   
String query ="SELECT * FROM `family_db` WHERE Parent_ID=?";
try {
    ps = db_connect.prepareStatement(query);
    
    ps.setString(1, famID);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) one.Famtbl.getModel();
    model.addColumn("Family_ID");
    model.addColumn("Family_Name");
    model.addColumn("Parent_ID");
    model.addColumn("Child_ID");
    while(rs.next())
    { 
        String n = rs.getString("Family_ID");
        String e= rs.getString("Family_Name");
        String r= rs.getString("Parent_ID");
        String d= rs.getString("Child_ID");
       
        // This will add row from the DB as the last row in the JTable. 
        //model.addRow(new Object[] {n, e, r, d});
        model.insertRow(one.Famtbl.getRowCount(), new Object[] {n, e, r, d});
    } 
    one.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Your `JTable`'s model is *not* a `DefaultTableModel`, and so casting it as one will not work. Instead, it appears to hold a `JTableBinding$BindingTableModel`.

Comment: [Here is one API entry for your table model](https://doc.formdev.com/beansbinding/org/jdesktop/swingbinding/JTableBinding.html). You obtained the table by binding, and it appears that you cannot simply add a row of data to this type of model. If you did, wouldn't it "break" the binding?

Comment: I removed the binding and just left the table blank. Now how do I get the table to update?

Comment: Your code is create a TableModel, but I don't see where you use the `setModel()` method to add the model to your JTable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627828/how-to-get-a-defaulttablemodel-objects-data-into-a-subclass-of-defaulttablemode/55635012#55635012 for a basic example.

Comment: **Tips for future questions:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.